# Idea set onClickListener. Game crashes at the start. (Java)

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, onclicklistener

My problem is in set `OnClickListener` I don't know why but always at the start my game crushes:

```
    ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagePlay);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            callListOfLevels();
        }
    });
    ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageQuit);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
public void callListOfLevels(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListOfLevels.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Remember to post what exception you are getting

Comment: Most likely it's an NPE because button1 or button2 is null, but hard to say because you're not showing a stack trace.

Comment: You're also not showing us enough of the code.